# Jquery multiselect comes back with one selected after POST

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a `Jquery multiselect` control

```
$(function () {
    $(".multiselect").multiselect().multiselectfilter({
        filter: function (event, matches) {
            if (matches.length != null && !matches.length) {
                // do something
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And this is linked to a `DropDownListFor`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ID, new MultiSelectList(Model.Employees, "Id", "Name"), "Please Select", new {multiple = "multiple", @class = "multiselect"})
```

When I press a button to post, the strongly typed model does send whoever has been selected in the list. Good. However, after the post, it only displays the first selected item in the `DropDownListFor` and not the others. I do send the model back when the post has happened with the IDs that are selected

```
// Model.ID which is a `int[]` is bounded to the `DropDownListFor` above has multiple values inside it. 
return View("View" Model)
```

Do I need to do something to the `Jquery` or the `razor` side to display the other selected items on postback?

Thanks

Comment: not sure if that's a parse error, but there is definetly something wrong with brackets in your code. there is an extra `});`

Comment: Sorry I didn't copy the whole JS, but you're right from what I posted!

Comment: It should work fine when you return the view. Have you tried without the `jquery multiselect` - just using the default html generated by `@Html.DropDownListFor`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke No, but I have just now and it only brings back one select, so therefore it isnt `jquery`, thats gives me more to go and invesitgate, thanks

Comment: Works for me although I use `@Html.ListBoxFor(..` and `new SelectList(..` but I think they generate the same html so should not be any difference

Comment: I am passing back a partial View as I am building the results from the model into a DevExpress Gridview, so that could be a problem

Comment: In the `MultiSelectList` I am not using the 3rd parameter which is a collection type, does this matter?

Comment: @user3428422, Rather that `new MultiSelectList(..`, try `new SelectList(..` (turns out there is a difference)

Comment: @user3428422 Are sure that the ID property of your model is an array or List.

Comment: @Venkat ID is a `List<int>` so this should be correct

Comment: @user3428422 Does the multiselectfilter do any filteration based on the dropdown onchange event.

Comment: I have commented out the jquery code and just debugging on the Multiselect right now

Comment: Thanks to everyone who helped, i found the soltuon below!

Answer (score 0):

In [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd470158(v=vs.118).aspx) present a constructor which receives selectedValues.

```
public MultiSelectList(
    IEnumerable items,
    string dataValueField,
    string dataTextField,
    IEnumerable selectedValues
)

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ID, new MultiSelectList(Model.Employees, "Id", "Name", Model.ToList()), "Please Select", new {multiple = "multiple", @class = "multiselect"})
```

Comment: Argh I see, however my model doesnt have `ToList()` I guess I need the collection that `x.ID` contains?

Comment: you should pass IEnumerable with selected IDs. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, OK, I found the problem.

I am not sure if its a .NET bug or something I need to change in my code, but changing

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ID, new MultiSelectList(Model.Employees, "Id", "Name"), "Please Select", new {multiple = "multiple", @class = "multiselect"})
```

To

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.ID, new MultiSelectList(Model.Employees, "Id", "Name"), "Please Select", new {multiple = "multiple", @class = "multiselect"})
```

Just magically works.

Now, In my searching for a solution, I never saw one post to say **"DropDownListFor's do not work with multiSelectList** or anything on them lines but I wou;ld be happy for someone to explain if its something I done wrong?

However, this may save someone searching for hours for the solution.

Thanks to everyone who helped :)